# opencsv values of one line are not separated

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I have a csv list like this:

```
abc;def;ghi;
jkl;mno;p;
qrs;tuv;wxy;
z;zz;zzz;
```

When parsing with opencsv like this:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("tmplist.csv"));
String[] nextLine;
int lineNumber = 0;
while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
    lineNumber++;
    System.out.println("Line # " + lineNumber);

    // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line  // no it's not
    System.out.println(nextLine[0]);
}
```

I get the following result:

> Line # 1
>
> abc;def;ghi;
>
> Line # 2
>
> jkl;mno;p;
>
> Line # 3
>
> qrs;tuv;wxy;
>
> Line # 4
>
> z;zz;zzz;

How can I get it to work like it is supposed to, i.e. the values in each line are separated in the `nextLine[]` array ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`CSVReader`](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVReader.html#CSVReader%28java.io.Reader%29) uses the default comma `,` character when parsing CSV files. Use the constructor that specifies the separator character instead:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("aaa.txt"), ';');
```